# PyTorch RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 14.12 GiB

Tags: pytorch

I have faced *Cuda out of memory* error for a simple fully connected layer model. I have tried `torch.cuda.empty_cache()` and `gc.collect()`. Also, I delete unnecessary variables by `del` and tried by reducing batch size. But the error does not resolved. Also, the error appears only for SUN datasets where 1440 test images are used to evaluate. But the code runs well for AWA2 datasets where no. of test images is 7913. I am using google colab here. I have used RTX 2060 too.
Here is the code snippet, where it gets error:

```
def euclidean_dist(x, y):
    # x: N x D
    # y: M x D
    torch.cuda.empty_cache()
    n = x.size(0)
    m = y.size(0)
    d = x.size(1)
    assert d == y.size(1)
    x = x.unsqueeze(1).expand(n, m, d)
    y = y.unsqueeze(0).expand(n, m, d)
    del n,m,d
    return torch.pow(x - y, 2).sum(2)

def compute_accuracy(test_att, test_visual, test_id, test_label):
    global s2v
    s2v.eval()
    with torch.no_grad():
        test_att = Variable(torch.from_numpy(test_att).float().to(device))
        test_visual = Variable(torch.from_numpy(test_visual).float().to(device))
        outpre = s2v(test_att, test_visual)
        del test_att, test_visual
        outpre = torch.argmax(torch.softmax(outpre, dim=1), dim=1)
    
    outpre = test_id[outpre.cpu().data.numpy()]
    
    #compute averaged per class accuracy
    test_label = np.squeeze(np.asarray(test_label))
    test_label = test_label.astype("float32")
    unique_labels = np.unique(test_label)
    acc = 0
    for l in unique_labels:
        idx = np.nonzero(test_label == l)[0]
        acc += accuracy_score(test_label[idx], outpre[idx])
    acc = acc / unique_labels.shape[0]
    return acc
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "GBU_new_v2.py", line 234, in <module>
    acc_seen_gzsl = compute_accuracy(attribute, x_test_seen, np.arange(len(attribute)), test_label_seen)   File "GBU_new_v2.py", line 111, in compute_accuracy
    outpre = s2v(test_att, test_visual)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 550, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)   File "GBU_new_v2.py", line 80, in forward
    a1 = euclidean_dist(feat, a1)   File "GBU_new_v2.py", line 62, in euclidean_dist
    return torch.pow(x - y, 2).sum(2)#.sqrt() # return: N x M RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 14.12 GiB (GPU 0;
15.90 GiB total capacity; 14.19 GiB already allocated; 669.88 MiB free; 14.55 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you have batches defined only for training, while during test you attempt to process the entire test set simultaneously.
You should split your test set into smaller "batches" and evaluate one batch at a time to combine all the batch scores at the end for one score for the model.

Comment: But the code runs perfectly for a larger test datasets which I have mentioned though I will try your mentioned procedure.

Comment: @TownimFaisal what is the size of the images in the different datasets? you should look at the entire `shape` of `test_att` and `test_visual` of the two datasets?

Comment: In Awa2 datasets, test_att is (7913,85) and test_visual is (7913,2048). For Sun datasets, test_att is (1440,102) and test_visual is (1440,2048). The problem occurs for Sun datasets.

Comment: @TownimFaisal does the error occurs when you run SUN after Awa2? what happens if you reverse the order? what happens if you only test SUN? can you get a memory usage report (https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/cuda.html#memory-management) before and after testing Awa2 and SUN?

Comment: It occurs even if I run only Sun datasets. I did torch.cuda.empty_cache()

Comment: @TownimFaisal what about https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/cuda.html#torch.cuda.memory_summary?

Comment: I have used torch.cuda.memory_summary in the beginning of script after import torch, but it gives same error as output.

Comment: Thanks, it's the main cause. I need to make batch of test images also.